# Learning CallBack Function: Trying to understand different forms of callback

Tags: javascript, callback

I am trying to learn callback, and after I read eloquent JS, it introduces callback as this format which Im not familiar with and it didn't explain how it works:

```
var merge = function(array1, array2, callback){  
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
   result[i] = array1[i] + array2[i];
  };
callback(result) 
};

merge([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], function(merged) {console.log(merged)});
```

but after I learned from code school, I tried to rewrite the format to this one:

```
var merge = function(array1, array2, callback){  
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
   result[i] = array1[i] + array2[i];
  };
return function() {console.log(result)}
};

merge([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8])();
```

im not sure if the way I understand call back is correct, but my rewrite works and shows the same result...can anyone explain to me how the first call back format works?

Answer (score 3):

On the second code, the function merge returns a function that prints an array.

So, the line `merge([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8])();` calls the function merge and execute the function that is returned.

I don't see it as a callback.

On the first code, the function merge receives a function as its third argument and executes this function passing an array to it (the line `callback(result)` )

This is what I understand by a callback: who calls the function merge is free to pass any function to it, and so, is free to execute any code over the array computed by the function merge.

For instance, considering the first definition of the function merge, one could do

```
merge([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], function(merged) { alert(merged[0]) });
```

to show the first element of the resulting array in a alert window.

Also, the first construction is asynchronous, while the second one is not.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking of it as a "callback" is probably the confusing part. In javascript, functions don't need to strictly be functions. They can be variables or parameters, as you're seeing in the example.

These will all produce the same results:

```
// as a variable
var myVariableFn = function() {
  console.log('executed function');
};
myVariableFn();

// as a named function
function myFn() {
  console.log('executed function');
}
myFn();

// as an anonymous function
(function() {
  console.log('executed function');
})();

// as a reference to another function
var myRefToFn = myFn;
myRefToFn();

// as a reference to the variable function
var myRefToVariableFn = myVariableFn;
myRefToVariableFn();
```

In your first example, it works because you're passing in an anonymous function as the last parameter, hence it's assigned to `callback`. Since you've assigned `callback` a function, you can execute it by saying `callback()`, as you would any other function.

It really boils down to the simple fact that you're passing functions around, which is a little easier to understand than trying to define what a "callback" is.

Since you're simply passing these to another function, you can use them all in the same way as a "callback", like this:

```
function useCallback(callbackParam) {
  callbackParam();
};

useCallback(myVariableFn);
useCallback(myFn);
useCallback(function() {
  console.log('executed function');
});
useCallback(myRefToFn);
useCallback(myRefToVariableFn);
```